# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError but with 70Kb of png image

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Ok first of all it's the first time I'm asking a question on stack so if I did something not "legal" don't hesitate to tell me...

Ok so now my real problem...

I'm trying to load to the memory some png files. Everything went really well my game works and all. But then I decided to change the resolution of my game because it was a bit sloppy (aliasing).

I change the bitmap from 1024*650 to 2048*1300. And doubled the size of all my png... At first I thought it would be ok because I only have 2.8 Mb in total. (And I have already loaded much more without any problem before).

But when I launch, my friendly eclipse tells me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at the fourth png file (so at roughly 70 Kb of files loaded). If I build it on my phone no problem and I have a moto G so really not a killer.

So my question is why it does that? And most of all how can I prevent this from happening. Really 2.5Mb of files should be manageable since I already did. So why does the resolution smoke my memory this way ?

thx in advance and sorry if I'm not clear...

Comment: "At first I thought it would be ok because I only have 2.8 Mb in total" -- how are you measuring this? Is it the sum of the file sizes? "so at roughly 70 Kb of files loaded" -- how are you measuring the 70 Kb? Is it the sum of the file sizes? Bear in mind that file sizes are meaningless, and that you need to focus instead on the bit depth (4 bytes by default) times the resolution (width x height in pixels) to get the actual memory footprint.

Comment: you are confusing the size of the file and the size of the image. pngs are compressed, bitmaps are not. 1300x2048x4 = 10Mb !

Comment: One file have to be less than 2mb. I am not sure

Comment: njzk2 1300x2048x4 = 10Mb   OOOOhhh

Comment: But then why when it was 1024*650 I loaded like 20 png and it was ok ?

Comment: I suppose you're loading one at a time to the native heap and then the memory is freed each time. When loading a PNG, it takes up far more memory than the file itself.

Comment: ok thx all of you I'm going to try something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2048×1300 pixels make 10 MiB (each pixel takes 4 bytes). That is quite a lot, especially low-level phones can have constraints as little as 16 MiB per application. You need to [make it more efficient](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).